# Fatal error: Class 'PEAR' not found in /home/user1/public_html/go-pear.php on line 697

Tags: email, cpanel, pear

When trying to install `PEAR` by running `go-pear.php` (from the root of a cPanel GoDaddy hosted account), I get the following error:

> Starting installation ... Loading zlib: ok
>
> Bootstrapping Installer...................
>
> Bootstrapping PEAR5.php............(remote) ok
>
> Bootstrapping PEAR.php............(remote) ok
>
> Bootstrapping Archive/Tar.php............(remote) ok
>
> Bootstrapping Console/Getopt.php............(remote) ok
>
> **Fatal error**: Class 'PEAR' not found in /home/alessio1/public_html/go-pear.php on line 697
>
> line 697 is the following: PEAR::setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_DIE,
>   "\n%s\n");

The file `go-pear.php` was taken directly from http://pear.php.net/go-pear without any modification.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Added answer for this on same question, [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815526/php-pear-installer-stuck-at-21/27542171#27542171

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error, and managed to solve it replacing the links stored in $bootstrap_files to :

```
$bootstrap_files = array(
    'PEAR5.php'            => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/pear-core/master/PEAR5.php',
    'PEAR.php'             => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/pear-core/master/PEAR.php',
    'Archive/Tar.php'      => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Archive_Tar/master/Archive/Tar.php',
    'Console/Getopt.php'   => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Console_Getopt/master/Console/Getopt.php',
);
```

Comment: It now kind of works but I still have "Preparing installer" which is stuck.

Comment: When I did this it worked. But due to PHP warnings which were pushing away the rest of the notifications it seemed as if it hanged.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error and found that KevinD's fix didn't work for me, but was able to figure something out based on it.  To solve the problem I replaced the line

```
'Console/Getopt.php'   => 'https://raw.github.com/pear/Console_Getopt/trunk/Console/Getopt.php',
```

with

```
'Console/Getopt.php'   => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Console_Getopt/trunk/Console/Getopt.php',
```

The install completed nearly instantly for me after this change.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .phar file: http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

It should work better.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attenction: Sometimes the problem is caused because of the **blocking of fsocket()** php function.
Server-to-server communication is sometimes used to commit abuses for example internet attacks.
Many free hosting companies block fsocket() function by default, and sometimes you have to authenticate yourself (providing information about you) to use this function.