# PHP Pear Installer stuck at 21%

Tags: php, installation, pear

I tried to install PHP Pear on my Webspace. I uploaded the installer file from http://pear.php.net/go-pear

I started the installer and everything seems to working except it stuck at 21% everytime.

This is the output of the installer, but I don't get any errors...

> Starting installation ...
>
> Loading zlib: ok
>
> Bootstrapping Installer...................
>
> Bootstrapping PEAR5.php............(remote) ok
>
> Bootstrapping PEAR.php............(remote) ok
>
> Bootstrapping Archive/Tar.php............(remote) ok
>
> Bootstrapping Console/Getopt.php............(remote) ok#

I have searched for a solution everywhere but nothing seems to work. Maybe someone can help me with this issue..

EDIT:

I recieve an error now, after I activated PHP Errors on my webspace (silly me).
Now I recieve the following errors:

> Fatal error: Class 'PEAR' not found in /customers/d/1/5/team-equipment.de/httpd.www/_pear/pearinstaller.php on line 697

After checking this issue I simply google the answer and found it on stackoverflow: [Fatal error: Class 'PEAR' not found in /home/user1/public_html/go-pear.php on line 697](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472216/fatal-error-class-pear-not-found-in-home-user1-public-html-go-pear-php-on-li)

This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

update links

```
$bootstrap_files = array(
'PEAR5.php'            => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/pear-core/master/PEAR5.php',
'PEAR.php'             => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/pear-core/master/PEAR.php',
'Archive/Tar.php'      => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Archive_Tar/master/Archive/Tar.php',
'Console/Getopt.php'   => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Console_Getopt/master/Console/Getopt.php',);
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23889357/169630