# PHP Pear Installer stuck at 30%

Tags: php, installation, pear

I tried to install PHP Pear on my Webspace. I uploaded the installer file from http://pear.php.net/go-pear

In the first run I got the following screen returned:

```
Starting installation ...
Loading zlib: ok

Bootstrapping Installer...................
Bootstrapping PEAR5.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping PEAR.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping Archive/Tar.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping Console/Getopt.php............(remote) ok
```

So I searched a long time but finaly found it in this article: [Fatal error: Class 'PEAR' not found in /home/user1/public_html/go-pear.php on line 697](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472216/fatal-error-class-pear-not-found-in-home-user1-public-html-go-pear-php-on-li)

```
Installation in progress ...
(If the page stops loading before the end of the installation, then just reload it)
30 %

Starting installation ...

Loading zlib: ok

Bootstrapping Installer...................
Bootstrapping PEAR5.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping PEAR.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping Archive/Tar.php............(remote) Not Foundok
Bootstrapping Console/Getopt.php............(remote) ok

Extracting installer..................
Downloading package: PEAR.............
```

I did as described but now it stops at 30% and I don't know how to get further.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance
Franz-Georg

As far as I can see the error log contains the following statements:

```
[Wed May 27 11:27:55.577416 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3097] [client ip:41115] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PEAR' not found in /var/www/vhosts/domain/pear/go-pear.php on line 697, referer: http://domain/go-pear.php?step=install
[Wed May 27 11:34:04.653829 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3097] [client ip:42225] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method PEAR::setErrorHandling() should not be called statically in /var/www/vhosts/domain/pear/go-pear.php on line 705, referer: http://domain/go-pear.php?step=install
[Wed May 27 11:34:05.012466 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3097] [client ip:42225] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Archive_Tar' not found in /var/www/vhosts/domain/pear/go-pear.php on line 742`, referer: http://domain/go-pear.php?step=install
```

domain means my domain.

Comment: You mean it stops at 30% whilst downloading? Well, there is little we can help in that, is there?

Comment: please try to use `http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`

Comment: @cweiske I tried to use this statement but only get a blank page

Comment: Where do you get a blank page? Download it and run `php go-pear.phar`.

Comment: @cweiske i can't run the command php go-pear.phar cause i have no console on my webhost!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no console on your web host, you cannot use the pear CLI tool to install packages even if you get PEAR installed.

Follow the [shared hosting installation docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php) then.