# Invalid block size: 240 when trying to install PEAR

Tags: php, pear

I am attempting to install the PEAR repository and the installation stops at 30% and, as it tries to extract the installer, returns and Invalid block size: 240 message.

The first time I tried installing, the install continually stopped at 21%, I found a solution to this here: [Fatal error: Class 'PEAR' not found in /home/user1/public_html/go-pear.php on line 697](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472216/fatal-error-class-pear-not-found-in-home-user1-public-html-go-pear-php-on-li/23889357#23889357)
After implementing this solution however, the install halts at 30%.

The following is what is returned during the PEAR install:

```
Starting installation ...
Loading zlib: ok

Bootstrapping Installer...................
Bootstrapping PEAR5.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping PEAR.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping Archive/Tar.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping Console/Getopt.php............(remote) ok

Extracting installer..................
Downloading package: PEAR............. Invalid block size : 240
```

Comment: The solution to most PEAR problems is usually "switch to Composer" ... :)

Comment: Looks like if the downloaded go-pear file is incomplete.